# Best way to enable or disable a button depending the situation

Tags: java, android

I have a map in Android (java), with a button which will be enabled if the distance between the two points in the map is less than 100 meters and will be disabled back when distance is greater than 100 meters.

What should be the best way to control the visibility of button?. I think using a thread is very heavy in this case and not the best way, but i don't have more ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a callback you can register with the map that fires every time a point is created or moved, that would be the perfect place to evaluate the enabled state of your button.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this method.

```
 public static boolean isInLocation(LatLng sourceLatLng, LatLng destinationLatLng) {
       return SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(
           sourceLatLng, destinationLatLng) < 100; 
 }
```

Please register a listener to location and make decision inside location update to enable or disable the button. :)